# How to change the window size of sqldeveloper on startup

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Windows 10 and sqldeveloper 19.2.1.247. I have my laptop's and another monitor. When I start sqldeveloper the window is very wide and I have shrink it. I see several posts about fixing font size, but none about window size. Is it possible to set initial window size and save it? Right now it spans both monitors and I have to shrink the width quite a bit. It is Oracle sqldeveloper.

Comment: Would this help? http://christian-gohmann.de/2018/10/25/running-sql-developer-on-high-dpi-screens/

Comment: It should remember the window size and position on launch - it does for me... Maybe your config file is locked or corrupt?

Comment: @Littlefoot That link is to change the font size, not the window size.I only saw results for changing font size when I did a search and didn't find any results for changing the window size, so I don't believe this deserves a down vote.

Comment: I think my problem was that I rebooted every morning (because of another problem) and didn't close sql developer, so the size didn't get saved. When testing this for this question, I did close sql developer and the size was saved. That doesn't explain why I changed the size in the file mentioned in the selected answer while sql developer was not running, but it overwrote my change when I started and exited sql developer. I currently have the size I want so I don't care about the overwriting.

Comment: Link I posted talks about *Compatibility* and DPI settings. I hoped that it would fix your problem. And - no, it wasn't me who downvoted your question. Anyway, I'm glad Alex helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Developer usually remembers the size and position when you relaunch. It seems either your config/cache is corrupt or locked, or something else is breaking when it tries to save on exit.

From a bit of poking around, the main window size and position is stored in

```
~\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system19.2.1.247.2212\system_cache\config\Preferences\com\oracle\jdeveloper\nbwindowsystem\Default\mainwnd.properties
```

so you could potentially manually change that (while it isn't running).

It might be simpler to do a reset, from the application's Window menu - which has option

> Reset Windows To Factory Settings

That clears all window/panel settings, not just the main window size/position, but as it seems to clear the cache it might clear the issue and let subsequent size/position changes be saved properly.

Comment: Thanks that was the file I needed. Strangely the last time I ran SQL developer it seemed to save the window size I changed it to, so I didn't need to change. In fact I changed the width to a smaller size and sql developer overwrote, but that is the size I want anyway.